# GZip compression in Perl maintains file path in gz-file on Windows

Tags: perl, gzip, cpan

I'm trying to send some gzipped files via e-mail. The packaging and sending of the files work fine, but when I open the .gz-files on a windows machine, the archive includes the filepath (in my case /tmp/feed) for each file. On Linux the filepath is not represented in the .gz-file.

Here is my code for packaging the files:

```
foreach my $input (glob($par{directory}.'*')) {
        my $output = "$input.gz";
        gzip $input => $output or die "GZIP failed: $GzipError";
}
```

Previously I tried

```
 gzip "<$par{directory}*.*>" => "<*.gz>" or die 'GZIP failed: '.$GzipError;
```

But it had the same result. 
Any hints on what I'm doing wrong? Is it possible that this problem has something to do with sending the files via email?

/solved
I used chdir($par{directory}) and gave gzip *.* as glob.

### Thanks for your help!

Comment: are the paths of the original uncompressed files absolute or relative?

Comment: The path to the original files is absolute (/tmp/feed/*.*)

Comment: then use a relative one to pass it to gzip, you just have to be careful to change the current directory and then change it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Compress/Gzip.html - According to the docs it also accepts a filehandle as input. Try using a filehandle instead of a file directly.

If this does not work, you can read the file into a scalar variable and pass this. This solution has the drawback, that it will needs lots of memory for large files.

Why using a filehandle: Depending on the way stream compressors (gzip, bzip2, xz, ...) are called, they either include filename or not. When you pass the data using a method where no filename is available, it will not be included.

Test example without error checks:

```
use IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip);

open FILE,">","test";
print FILE "Test";
close FILE;

open $fn,"<","test";
gzip $fn => "testnn.gz";
gzip "test" => "testwn.gz";
```

Comment: Reading the file into a scalar variable is not an option, since the files I'm working with can be several GB in size.

I've tried using a filehandle 

foreach my $input (glob($par{directory}.'*')) {
    $fh = new IO::File "<$input" or die 'Can\'t open file: '.$!;
    my $buffer;
    gzip $fh => \$buffer or die "GZIP failed: $GzipError";
    close $fh;
    $fh = new IO::File ">$input.gz";
    print $fh, $buffer;
    close $fh;
}

But that doesn't work either. Now I'm not even getting any data in the zipped files.

Comment: I attached a test example which does exactly what you want. One file "testwn.gz" is with name, the other one "testnn.gz" without name.

Answer (score 1):

The "**Name**" option in **IO::Compress::Gzip** allows you to explicitly set the filename that is stored in the gzip file.

Something like this will remove all the path components from the filename before storing in the gzip file

```
foreach my $input (glob($par{directory}.'*')) {
    my $output = "$input.gz";
    my $name = $input ;
    $name =~ s#^.*/##;
    gzip $input => $output, Name => $name or die "GZIP failed: $GzipError";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I had the same issue. It worked for me.

```
my $curr_work_dir = getcwd;
my $file_dir = dirname($input_file);
my $input_filename = basename($input_file);

$output_file=$input_filename.$gzip_extn;

chdir $file_dir;
gzip $input_filename => $output_file or die "\n\nGzip compression failed for $input_file";
chdir $curr_work_dir;
```